# How to implement Devops environment test section?

Tags: testing

In our university, our instructor gave Devops environment improvement as a project. I am in the test section of this project and I have a few questions that I can not understand.

Our instructor said that we must write an adapter that interacts with interface(a other group should provide interface) and allows people in this environment to test their own code. Then he wanted us to investigate the Cucumber, Selenium and Junit.

If the code-owner people are going to write their own tests, why am I learning Cucumber? Will not the man who wrote the code write his test with Cucumber?

I am very confused in this regard, please help me with Devops test title.

Comment: Nevermind then, you should [edit] your question to better explain what you're doing, it's highly unclear what Devops has to do here.

Answer (score 1):

A software development team will typically have to test their software. One kind of test that can be done is UI testing, typically done through Selenium and the likes. The stack of services required to run UI tests systematically is often the hardest to set up. Companies like BrowserStack specialize in minimizing that set up task for developers.

I suggest you investigate how to set up Selenium along with a few browsers to allow the other group to test their software. This task will typically revolve around X11, xvfb, x11vnc, selenium/selenium-grid and one or multiple browsers. Docker images from the selenium team itself are pre-built and offer a great level of functionality out of the box.